# How to integrate a native Android navigation drawer in a Hybrid MobileFirst Platform app

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm building a hybrid mobile app for Android with IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7. Yesterday I created a side menu using native code. It works well but when I try to integrate it with the hybrid app - to load the local file the side menu does not work. I am following this [Android Slide Menu](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) tutorial.

I inserted the following code into the `onCreate` function:

```
WL.createInstance(this);

WL.getInstance().showSplashScreen(this);

WL.getInstance().initializeWebFramework(getApplicationContext(), this);
```

Can anyone help me on how to integrate the native android slide menu to the app?

My project: https://github.com/nguyengiangdev/HybridApp

Comment: It will help if you'll add your actual implementation....

Comment: @IdanAdar: this is my repo on github you can help me   https://github.com/nguyengiangdev/HybridApp

Comment: Is there any real reason why, in a hybrid app, you opt to the native component (even though in theory you could) instead of an existing solution in JavaScript which are far easier to integrate to a Hybrid app? See here: http://www.queness.com/post/14244/side-out-sidebar-navigation-javascript-solutions

Comment: Hi @IdanAdar, i find solution i use cordova plugins to handle between native and javascript. Thanks Idan Adar

Comment: Can you please write a detailed answer below instead of a comment?

Comment: Can you please write the full solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> Hi @IdanAdar, i find solution i use cordova plugins to handle between
>   native and javascript.